# SELinux contexts with NFS shares

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nfs, selinux

I'm trying to set up an NFS share between 2 CentOS servers (filesrv & websrv) for a folder that needs to be readable & writeable by the Apache process. I'm having trouble with the writeable side of this, which I've narrowed down to SELinux configuration: Apache can write to the share if I `setenforce 0` on the NFS client.

The relevant line in the exports file for the NFS server is:

`/data/files/sitefiles websrv(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`

The SELinux context for the shared folder on the NFS server is:

`system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0`

The entry in my fstab on the NFS client is:

`filesrv:/data/files/sitefiles /var/www/html/webroot/files nfs context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0" 0 0`

As far as I can tell, this should mount the NFS share with the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context, but when I check it, it's actually:

`system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`

What could be causing it to apply the stricter context to the share?

Answer (score 9):

The simple solution should be to use the SELinux boolean `httpd_use_nfs` to allow your webserver to display and write content stored on a NFS share:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs=1
```

Comment: I've tried setting this, but it doesn't seem to help. NB Apache is able to read from the share regardless of whether the boolean's on or off.

Comment: What denials are you actually getting? `ausearch -m avc -c httpd`

Comment: They're all in the form:     avc:  denied  { associate } for  pid=2202 comm="httpd" name="js" scontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=filesystem

Comment: I don't believe a boolean exists that will allow httpd to _write_ to an NFS share - at least not until the SELinux extensions for NFS are generally available. You've got a couple of years to wait for that, though...

Comment: setting the filecontext to `public_content_rw_t` or `public_content_t` for the directory on the server-side should allow the `httpd` process read/write permissions.

Comment: This answer worked for me (RHEL7).  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was occurring because I was mounting multiple NFS shares from the same server, not all of which had the same context.

As per the [RedHat documentation on multiple NFS mounts](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Mounting_File_Systems-Multiple_NFS_Mounts.html), I needed to add *nosharecache* to my fstab line for the mounts. The correct SELinux context is then applied on a mount-by-mount basis.

The working line in my fstab is as follows:

```
filesrv:/data/files/sitefiles /var/www/html/webroot/files nfs nosharecache,context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0" 0 0
```